# Off being used to say "not to live on a certain place"?

Tags: prepositions, word-meaning, vocabulary

I've seen some sentences with **off** to apparently say "*not to live on a certain place*"

For instance:

> We live *off* the campus
>
> I used to live *off* that farm,but after my grandpa invited me...
>
> I live *off* the Main Street.

My question is: *Do those sentences respectively mean:*

> We *don't live on* the campus.
>
> I *didn't use to live on that farm*, but [...]
>
> I *do not live on the Main Street*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We live off campus

Means "we don't live on campus".

> I live off the farm.

Most typically means the farm is your means of living. Either you make your living by selling the products of the farm, or you actually eat the food produced on the farm. Possibly, you also live in a house that's part of the farm.

> I live off Main Street.

Means you live on a street that crosses Main Street, and you probably live fairly close to Main Street.